# Using Application.Run to evaluate Worksheet function passed as string

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have essentially a simple syntax question concering Application.Run. I want to write a bit of code where I pass a UDF a string coantaining the name of a worksheet function, e.g. 'iserror' or some other UDF returning boolean. The function will then be exectued for each cell within the passed range and do something depending on result.

However, I have not been able to work out the proper Syntax. Error Messages Change along with my Trials, but non are particularly helpfull. e.g.:

`?hrCull(Range("Data!A1:B10"),"Worksheetfunction.iserror", False)`

(Error message in German, I'll try my best to translate, but it probably won't 100% match the English Version):

Runtime error 1004:

The macro 'Worksheetfunction.iserror' can not be exectued. The macro may not be available in this worksheet or macros have been deactivated.

Of course, macros have not been deactivated, but it isn't really a macro anyway. Also tried without the leading 'Worksheetfunction', same error message.

In my code the call Looks like this:

```
Public Function hrCull(r As Range, func As String, Optional invert As Boolean = False) As Range
    Dim c           As Range
    Dim selector    As Boolean
    ...
    selector = Application.Run(func, c)
    ...
end function
```

I omitted code not relevant.

So what is the proper Syntax?

Misc:

```
- I'm Aware that I can not assert that the passed function returns a boolean.
- Excel 2016 on Windows 7
```

Comment: Use `Application.Evaluate` instead of `Application.Run`

Comment: @Tom : Well, that at least changed the error message - I'm afraid I will Need some help on the correct Syntax in that case as well.

Comment: What is the error message? To get this to work you would need to pass the Excel function not the VBA function. You're also passing a range to `WorksheetFunction.IsError` when it only expects one cell. Your syntax should be more like `Application.Evaluate("IsError(""A1"")")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the `WorksheetFunction.` prefix, Evaluate doesn't like it as Evaluate is for worksheet functions.

In your function, use:

```
selector = Application.Evaluate(func & "(" & c.Address & ")")
```

To test, use:

```
Debug.Print hrCull(Range("A1"), "ISERROR")
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using CallByName:

```
selector = CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, "IsError", VbMethod, c)
```

Comment: CallByName is one of the 'reflection' methods of VB6 language. It is suported in VBA too, but not VBA specific.
@YeOldHinnerk: it worked for me - I tested it before posting. The argument c, for IsError must be a single-cell-range. Did you account for that?

Comment: @HooNose Yes, it will always only be called for a single cell, I ensured that. One Thing I was wondering is, if it could be language related. I'm in Germany, so in the spreadsheet, the function would be called "Istfehler", while in vba it would be "iserror" - what would it be in this particular callbyname method?

Comment: @YeOldHinnerk I'm in germany too and have a german office version installed. But it's still "IsError" - the same name you would call directly in VB code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off declaring your own `Enum` and adding the functions that you want into this. Then execute them using built in syntax instead of trying to evaluate a string

```
Public Enum xlSheetFunction
    xlIsError
End Enum

Public Function hrCull(r As Range, func As xlSheetFunction, Optional Invert As Boolean = False) As Range
    Dim selector As Boolean

    Select Case func
        Case xlIsError
            selector = WorksheetFunction.IsError(r)
    End Select

    Debug.Print selector

    Set hrCull = r
End Function

Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print hrCull(Range("A1"), xlIsError)
End Sub
```

Comment: I will probably actually go for this solution. I checked the answer below however, since it answers the exact question.